# Plot of errors from a Logistic regression

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have fitted a `logistic regression` on my data, for which I have below example,

```
    library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

Model = glm(vs ~ wt + disp, 
                      data = mtcars, 
                      family = "binomial")

Pred = predict(Model)
Pred_Prob = exp(Pred) / (1+exp(Pred))
Error = (mtcars[, 'vs'] - Pred_Prob) / sqrt(Pred_Prob * (1 - Pred_Prob))
plot(Pred_Prob, Error)

This gives below plot
```

[image]

I wonder if this is a natural plot expected from fitting a `logistic regression`? Why am I seeing 2 converging lines? If not, what else can be done to improve the model fitting for above dataset?

Comment: `predict.glm` already returns probabilities. What are you trying to show on this plot?

Comment: `predict.glm(model)` gives values `-5.193` etc. So I don't think it predicts probability directly. Looks like it provides `log odd`. I am trying to understand, for a good `logistic` fit, how this plot should look like? Is above model good fit? Is there any clustering in `residuals`?

Comment: The lower line is for those cars with V-shaped cylinder layouts ($vt=0$) and the upper line for those cars with straight cylinders ($vt=1$).  This is what you would expect to see on a residuals plot when predicting a binary variable

Comment: @Henry Yes it was a mistake. I have corrected the code and modified the plot. Also could you please further elaborate your statement? Why I see downward trend in this error plot? Should not this plot look like random fluctuation for ideal fit?

Comment: Since `Pred_Prob` must be between $0$ and $1$, the residuals `mtcars[, 'vs'] - Pred_Prob` must be positive when $vt=1$ and negative when $vt=0$: this leads to the two lines.  Since you have fitted the model to the data, you would expect the residuals on the lower line tend to be closer to $0$ when the predicted probabilities are closer to $0$ (the left side of the lower line) and the residuals on the upper line tend to be closer to $0$ when the predicted probabilities are closer to $1$ (the right  side of the upper line) making both lines downward sloping.

Comment: If you had not divided by `sqrt(Pred_Prob*(1-Pred_Prob))` then both lines would be straight with slopes of $-1$

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. So in that case it can be concluded that the fitted model is good fit to the data, right?

Comment: I have one more important question. If I need to check the `Residual` e.g independences, qq plot etc, should I need to do this separately for `vs = 1` and `vs = 0`? i.e. separate tests for positive and negative errors?

Answer (score 2):

It may help you to read my answer to [Interpretation of plot (glm.model)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139624/7290).  In brief, I would not (do not) use those plots for logistic regression.  The first question I would ask is: what are you trying to find out?  Is a plot helpful for discovering that?  What plot might do so?  Etc.  For example, you mention looking at a qq-plot.  For a logistic regression, the outcome is binary; thus, the distribution is the Bernoulli or binomial.  The data are not normal, nor need they be.  We know this in advance.  There could be a case where there is value in looking at the qq-plot, but I'm not sure what it would be *in general*.

With respect to assessing a fitted logistic regression model, one thing you might want to check is whether a linear function of X was appropriate (assuming you used that).  In such a case, rather than looking at a plot of the residuals vs X, as I might with a linear model, I might compare the fitted model to something non-parametric, such as a LOWESS fit.  To illustrate this idea, consider the example below (adapted from [ROC curve crossing the diagonal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307483/7290)):

```
## data
Cond.1 = c(2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7,
           3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.1, 4.2, 4.4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.6,
           4.6, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 4.9, 5.5, 5.5, 5.7)
Cond.2 = c(2.3, 2.4, 2.6, 3.1, 3.7, 3.7, 3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 4.8, 4.9, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.7,
           5.8, 5.9, 5.9, 6.0, 6.0, 6.1, 6.1, 6.3, 6.5, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1,
           7.2, 7.2, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.6, 10, 10.1, 12.5)
dat    = stack(list(cond1=Cond.1, cond2=Cond.2))
ord    = order(dat$values)
dat    = dat[ord,]  # now the data are sorted

## logistic regression model & LOWESS fit
lr.model1 = glm(ind~values, dat, family="binomial")  # straight line fit
lr.preds1 = predict(lr.model1, data.frame(values=seq(2.3,12.5,by=.1)), type="response")
LOWESS    = loess((as.numeric(ind)-1)~values, dat, degree=0)  # non-parametric fit
LOWESS.pd = predict(LOWESS, data.frame(values=seq(2.3,12.5,by=.1)))

## here I plot the data, the model, & overlay a LOWESS fit
windows()
  with(dat, plot(values, ifelse(ind=="cond2",1,0), 
                 ylab="predicted probability of condition2"))
  lines(seq(2.3,12.5,by=.1), lr.preds1, lwd=2, col="red")
  lines(seq(2.3,12.5,by=.1), LOWESS.pd, lwd=2, col="blue")
  legend("bottomright", legend=c("model", "LOWESS"), lwd=2, col=c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]